# Pug use in Parcel

Tags: html, pug, parceljs

Just beginning to use Parcel with Pug. I am running into issues in how to use a link in pug to different pug files.

I have two pug files in my src directory, index.pug and tradgard.pug. I also have a nav include which is used by both the mentioned pug files. 
This is the code for the nav include:

```
nav#nav.flex-nav
    ul
      li
        a(href='/') Hem
      li
        a(href='#') Vår story
      li
        a(href='/tradgard') Trädgården
      li
        a(href='#') Matsal
      li
        a(href='#') Matevent
      li
        a(href='#') Album
      li
        a(href='#booking') Boka bord
      li
        a(href='#') Shop
```

This gives the following html:

```
<nav class="flex-nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Hem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vår story</a></li>
      <li><a href="/tradgard">Trädgården</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Matevent</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Album</a></li>
      <li><a href="#booking">Boka bord</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The link is to the index file, as one can see, the link:

```
li
  a(href='/tradgard') Trädgården
```

is translated into:

```
<li><a href="/tradgard">Trädgården</a></li>
```

So in browser from the server if I am on the index page and click that link it goes to tradgard, in the url window, but it still is showing the index page in the browser.

If I change nav include to:

```
li
  a(href='/tradgard.pug') Trädgården
```

resulting in the following html:

```
<li><a href="/tradgard.pug">Trädgården</a></li>
```

the index page looses it styling completely, but if I now click the link to 
tradgard, it does show up properly in the browser with the following url,

> http://localhost:1234/tradgard.html

I checked the property inspector for the index page, and css link is gone, but for the tradgard page, the css link is in the  the header.

Why am I getting this strange behavior, I suspect that I am coding the nav include links in a wrong way through, as I am getting a lot of errors for:

> "Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from CSSStyleSheet"

in the property inspector.

I don't know if this is me coding the nav include links wrong or if it may be a parcel issue.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "parcel_pug_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel serve src/index.pug",
    "prod": "parcel build src/*.pug -d public --public-url ./"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "1.12.0",
    "pug": "2.0.3",
    "sass": "1.17.2"
  }
}
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**The proper way to reference tradgard.pug from index.pug is `a(href='/tradgard.pug')`.**

- The Parcel builder needs to know the file extension in order to know how to process it.
- The Parcel builder does not seem to do complex handling of URL's that do not end in filenames (such as looking for files/directories that match).

Likewise, the Parcel dev server handles URL's without filenames as if your project is a single page app (SPA). If the URL does not end in a filename, the index.html file is loaded and passed the entire URL. If your project is not an SPA, this might not be intuitive. (This is the reason the Parcel dev server served the index page when you clicked the link. If you keep clicking the link, notice the relative path keeps being appended to the URL.)

**There is a method of using links without filenames like `/tradgard` in index.pug:**

1. Rename "tradgard.pug" to "index.pug", and put it in a directory named "tradgard"
2. When running Parcel specify multiple entry points, one for each index.pug. You might be able to use wild cards like this: `parcel src/index.html src/**/index.html`
3. The parcel dev server will still fail to serve the expected pages, but you can use an alternative dev server like [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/).

---

The CSS errors seem to be a separate issue, and I cannot comment on it because I know neither how you included the CSS file, nor what the CSS files contain. (Try opening a new question.)